# Column width on table is not following grid container width on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to build a table with Bootstrap 4 grid container. Everything looks great (styling, alignment,...) except for one problem: the table doesn't follow the grid container as expected. It seems like only the first column expands/shrinks when I try to resize my browser.

I used the `display` property to build my table to solve alignment problems, but once I try putting `col-#` as class names for the columns, it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.my-table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-table-row-header {
  display: table-header-group;
  height: 50px;
}

.first-header-column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-table-body {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.my-table-row {
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  display: table-row;
}

.row-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.c-column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid no-gutters">
  <div class="my-table col-9 table">
    <div class="my-table-row-header row">
      <div class="first-header-column col-1 row-cell">
        <span class="c-column">c</span>
      </div>
      <div class="second-column col-4 row-cell">
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="third-column col-4 row-cell">
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-table-body">
      <div class="my-table-row row">
        <div class="first-column col-1 row-cell">
          <span class="c-column">c</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="third-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="my-table-row row">
        <div class="first-column col-1 row-cell">
          <span class="c-column">c</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="third-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zn5oby6/2/

If you try resizing your browser, you'll see the first column resizes accordingly. I expect it to follow the grid container size strictly.

P.S. Since my table contains other components (not just text), I would like to keep the `display` properties to assure my styling is on point if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on what the question is exactly, but I noticed the col-9 needed to be in its own div. Then to equal 12 columns add the col-3 div after.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style>
 .my-table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-table-row-header {
  display: table-header-group;
  height: 50px;
}

.first-header-column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-table-body {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.my-table-row {
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  display: table-row;
}

.row-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.c-column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container-fluid no-gutters">
  <div class="col-9">
  <div class="my-table  table">
    <div class="my-table-row-header row">
      <div class="first-header-column col-1 row-cell">
        <span class="c-column">c</span>
      </div>
      <div class="second-column col-4 row-cell">
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="third-column col-4 row-cell">
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-table-body">
      <div class="my-table-row row">
        <div class="first-column col-1 row-cell">
          <span class="c-column">c</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="third-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="my-table-row row">
        <div class="first-column col-1 row-cell">
          <span class="c-column">c</span>
        </div>
        <div class="second-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="third-column col-4 row-cell">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I misunderstood bootstrap width column... What a noob I am lol...

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a way around it. Instead of using `display: table-cell` and all that `vertical-align` and `text-align` crap, I used `display: flex` which respected the bootstrap grid column width (which I'm still not sure why?).